# Obstruction to lifting a map from the base space to the total space.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory, obstruction-theory

Suppose $\pi :E \to B$ is a fibration with fibre $F$ above a chosen base point. Then I am trying to solve when a map $f$ from a manifold $M$ to $B$ lift to a map $g:M \to E$. The answer given is they are cohomology classes of form $H^{n+1}(M;\pi_n(F))$. I am unable to prove this.

In the special case where the manifold $M$ is $S^n$. This is equivalent to asking when is an element of $\pi_n(B)$ in the image of an element of $\pi_n(E)$. Now using the long exact sequence of homotopy groups for a fibration we get that corresponding element of $\pi_{n-1}(F)$ has to be zero. But this is precisely $H^{n}(S^n;\pi_{n-1}(F))$. But I am unable to prove in the case of a general manifold. I am guessing the idea is to use the CW structure of manifold but I do not really understand how. if anyone can give any hints it would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean $H^n(M;\pi_{n-1}(F))$ perhaps or not? Is $n$ the dimension of $M$?

Comment: @Malkoun I am not entirely sure if my interpretation is right but I think it is all cohomology classes of that form where $n$ ranges over $0$ to dim $M-1$

Comment: Look at the following [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1756946/local-coefficients-involved-in-the-obstruction-class-for-a-lift-of-a-map) for a related discussion.

Comment: You have the right idea: induction cell-by-cell is the way to go.  See section 7.10 in Davis & Kirk's AT book for a reference.